# ByteBuffer: Write to, then go back to the beginning of the buffer and write before all the data that was previously written (prepending?)

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, prepend

I'm still a little shaky on using *ByteBuffer*'s.  What I want to do is have data written to the ByteBuffer, then go to the beginning of the ByteBuffer and write a byte before all of that data (the payload of a packet is written, then prepended with the header.)  How can I do that?

Diagram:

Buffer starts with:

```
|  PAYLOAD  |
```

Buffer after op code header is added (after what I want to do):

```
|  HEADER  |  PAYLOAD  |
```

The | just being separators of the kind of data, not literally anything.

Comment: Create a second `ByteBuffer`, `put` the header then `put` the first `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: Is there a way to send two buffers together?  I'm unaware.  Thanks

Comment: What you want is to reserve space at the beginning for the header, add the payload then rewind to `byte[0]` and make the header.

Comment: I'll look into rewinding and marking -- I forgot about that completely.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called 'scatter-gather I/O' and it is supported by `ScatteringByteChannel.read(ByteBuffer[])` and `GatheringByteChannel.write(ByteBuffer[])`. Note the arrays. These interfaces are supported by `FileChannel`, `SocketChannel`, and `DatagramSocketChannel` and the Pipe channels.

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot about this completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(HEADER_SZ + PAYLOAD_SZ);
bbuf.position(HEADER_SZ);
for(int i=0; i < PAYLOAD_SZ; i++)
    bbuf.put(payload[i]);
bbuf.rewind();
for(int i=0; i < HEADER_SZ; i++)
    bbuf.put(header[i]);
```

I've made assumptions about byte indexing your source data. It would be better to bulk put but this is a start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add another answer to this question, as I've experienced this issue today, and the accepted solution wasn't that helpful in my case.

To solve my problem, I defined an `int` that will represent the amount of data (in bytes) that the `ByteBuffer` will hold, as well as a `Queue<Consumer<ByteBuffer>>` as follows:

```
/**
 * An {@code int} representing the amount
 * of bytes that this {@link OutgoingPacket}
 * will send.
 */
private int size;

/**
 * A {@link Queue} that lazily writes data to the
 * backing {@link ByteBuffer}.
 */
private final Queue<Consumer<ByteBuffer>> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

Next, I created methods such as `putByte`, `putInt`, etc.

```
/**
 * Writes a single {@code byte} to this
 * {@link Packet}'s payload.
 *
 * @param b
 *      An {@code int} for ease-of-use,
 *      but internally down-casted to a
 *      {@code byte}.
 * @return
 *      The {@link Packet} to allow for
 *      chained writes.
 */
public OutgoingPacket putByte(int b) {
    size++;

    queue.offer(payload -> payload.put((byte) b));
    return this;
}
```

Finally, I created a `send` method where the `ByteBuffer` is allocated and passed the respective data.

```
/**
 * Transmits this {@link OutgoingPacket} to
 * a specific client.
 *
 * @param channels
 *      A variable amount of {@link AsynchronousSocketChannel}s.
 *
 * TODO: Send to {@link Client} instead.
 */
public void send(AsynchronousSocketChannel... channels) {
    /*
     * Allocate a new buffer with the size of
     * the data being added, as well as an extra
     * two bytes to account for the opcode and the
     */
    ByteBuffer payload = ByteBuffer.allocate(size + 2);

    /*
     * Write the opcode to the buffer.
     */
    payload.put((byte) opcode);

    /*
     * Write the length to the buffer.
     */
    payload.put((byte) size);

    /*
     * Add the rest of the data to the buffer.
     */
    queue.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(payload));

    /*
     * Flip the buffer so the client can immediately
     * read it on arrival.
     */
    payload.flip();

    /*
     * Write the buffer to the channels.
     */
    for (AsynchronousSocketChannel channel : channels) {
        channel.write(payload);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will provide insight to those who run into this problem in the future!